# calling on a javascript push service via c++

Tags: javascript, c++, http, pusher

I have a Qt application that needs to call on a javascript push service. Basically there is no \endf in the http. (a currency ticker)

```
<script src="//js.pusher.com/2.2/pusher.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var pusher = new Pusher("cb65d0a7a72cd94adf1f");
var channel = pusher.subscribe("ticker.160");
channel.bind("message", function(data) {
  //console.log(data);
  var topbuy = data.trade.topbuy;
  console.log("Price: ", topbuy.price,
              "Quantity:", topbuy.quantity);
});
</script>
```

How do I execute this existing code in C++? (make it a C++ ticker and not just a JavaScript ticker)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://pusher.com/docs/pusher_protocol, they use WebSockets for communication.
So you probably want to look at some library like http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp or the Casablanca SDK from Microsoft https://casablanca.codeplex.com/

With one of these it should be fairly easy to connect and receive the Pusher messages.

Comment: The pusher documentation is horrible and I would have to guess all of the http. I am receiving the updates just fine now via javascript and I would like to stay there. It solves more issues than the websockets create. Leaving that part of the system is Javascript makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood your question. You want to embed a JavaScript interpreter into your C++ application and interface with it? (Incidentally I think the Pusher documentation looks quite good but I haven't worked with it so I didn't look that closely).

Comment: I am 100% finished with Pusher. I only need to suck the existing data from JavaScript(only). Yes, I need to be able to read the JavaScript interpreter.

Comment: If you say "read the JavaScript interpreter" you should probably elaborate on your setup and development environment. Are you on Windows 8 CLR? Qt? Another framework that already provides JS-C++-bridging? Have you already embedded V8 yourself?

Comment: actually execute the Javascript code and then read the returned http. I am looking at QtWebkits as a possible solution. I just haven't found any decent sample code.

Comment: Here is why I really don't think a traditional websocket will work  http://i62.tinypic.com/14v1vz5.png  How am I going to produce this key?

Comment: From what I can tell, QML is the only path.

Comment: So you don't have any way to execute JS yet? While embedding V8 is certainly possible, it's not for the faint of heart, so to speak. In my experience with the Cassandra REST library, it should "automagically" add all the required surrounding data, making the WebSocket requests described in the Pusher API quite painless. It's certainly the way I'd go first.

Comment: at this time I still have no solution. qml is choking on my javascript event.

Comment: Are you using Qt anyway or did you pull in QML just for this? If this is QML-specific, you should consider editing your question to mention it and also tagging it accordingly.

Comment: I am trying/working in both codeblocks and Qt. I had some functions I wrote in Qt in the passed as was trying that. Either is fine.

Comment: by "automagically", do you mean 'escape IP and the entire stack'? no port, no nothing? Just connect? This makes no sense...  Kindly provide parameters or expect silly questions.   :/